# A Fact Stated in Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sum

In his text Multiplicative Number Theory on page 9, Davenport mentions that another means of expanding the L-function is known and then mentions the fact that, 
$$
\mathcal{F} \sum_{n=1,n \; odd} \frac{1}{n}e_q(mn) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{4} \pi & if \; 0<m<q/2 \\ -\frac{1}{4} \pi & if \; q/2<m<q \end{cases} 
$$
Davenport mentions that this result is derived using the logarithmic series. I could not find the same symbol that Davenport used in the text so I used $\mathcal{F}$ since I suspected it was a Fourier Transform. Is my suspicion correct ? How exactly is this result derived ?

Comment: it's an "I", the imaginary part

Comment: How does he derive it ?

Comment: Look at the equation in the middle of page 8: $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac1{n}e^{in\theta}=\dots$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.